# insert html raw codes to a post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My question is I want to add `<div>` into the post as it shows up here. But if I use the html format of wordpress, this tag will be interpreted as a real html tag. How to disable the function of this tag but just display it on the post?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a section about writing code in your posts [right in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts).

TL;DR: You need to use HTML character entities, and wrap your code in either `<pre>` or `<code>` tags. Example:

```
<code>&lt;div&gt;</code>
```

This will output as `<div>`.